# How to remove contents type drupal advanced search page

Tags: search

When Drupal does a search, and returns no results, an advanced search form is displayed. The form contains a list of content types. There are a couple of content types on our site, but these should be hidden from the user, e.g the end user shouldn't see "contentType", "newType".

I don't want to limit the results, just restrict the user's ability to filter the results using the types.

I've tried looking at the search templates, but couldn't find a reference to the fields.

Any ideas on where I find the correct type or turn off this field?

Answer (score 2):

Advanced Search field can be disabled in Permissions settings (it should be disabled by default).
[image]

If you rather want to leave Advanced Search, but limit to specific content types, you can 1) Use [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module, as advised by @Lance or 2) Dig through `modules\search\*.*` directory to see which function controls the content type of the Advanced Search options, after which you can use your own module to override the settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to change the form to your needs. In your case just go and unset the GUI elements you don't want to show up from the $form array.

If you don't know the form ID just implement an empty hook_form_alter and use [dpm](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7)() to print the form IDs. You need the devel module and the "Access developer information" permissino to see the output of dpm().

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) Module. With this you can specify which role can search which content types and some other nice features.